# Install package robot-player on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install Player on Ubuntu 16.04.

Ref http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/ and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/robot-player

It seems to me that the robot-player was created for Trusty, and is thus not available for Xenial Xerus?

When I try to install it I get this:

```
frode@xenialxerus:~$ sudo apt-get install robot-player
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package robot-player is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'robot-player' has no installation candidate
```

I've also tried to download the sourcecode from sourceforge, but it fails during 'make' with this;

```
(...)
from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
from /home/frode/Downloads/player-3.0.2/client_libs/libplayerc++/playerclient.cc:48:
/home/frode/Downloads/player-3.0.2/client_libs/libplayerc++/playerclient.cc: In member function ‘void PlayerCc::PlayerClient::RunThread()’:
/home/frode/Downloads/player-3.0.2/client_libs/libplayerc++/playerclient.cc:171:34: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
  boost::xtime_get(&xt, boost::TIME_UTC);
                              ^
client_libs/libplayerc++/CMakeFiles/playerc++.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'client_libs/libplayerc++/CMakeFiles/playerc++.dir/playerclient.o' failed
make[2]: *** [client_libs/libplayerc++/CMakeFiles/playerc++.dir/playerclient.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:612: recipe for target 'client_libs/libplayerc++/CMakeFiles/playerc++.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [client_libs/libplayerc++/CMakeFiles/playerc++.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any tips as to how I can get Player working on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is xenial & for it robot-player doesn't have any deb package . Just download the deb file http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/player/robot-player_3.0.2+dfsg-4.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb and try `dpkg -i  robot-player_3.0.2+dfsg-4.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb` .
You may need to satisfy dependencies manually. That deb file for trusty x64 , try that or find yours on the download section of http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/robot-player

Comment: I started doing that now, and get a lot of unmet dependencies, like you said. What is the proper approach to fix these dependencies? Download a .deb package for each of them? It's missing these: libboost-system1.54.0, liblodo3.0, libplayerc++3.0, libplayerc3.0, libplayercommon3.0, libplayercore3.0, libplayerdrivers3.0, libplayerinterface3.0, libplayertcp3.0  and libplayerwkb3.0.

Comment: I have checked these packages , most of them are not available for xenial.
Now you have two options ,first download debs of these one by one (You may encounter more dependencies) second (I think) https://github.com/rtv/Stage is the project github page so have a look at INSTALL.txt . They have provided guidelines for compiling it on Ubuntu (11.04) . It may help you .